# How to properly run JUnit tests on SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, unit-testing, junit

I have a class that has different methods that operate with SQLite. Those include `add` , `remove`, `update` etc. I am trying to run a couple tests using JUnit and the problem is that it runs the tests in a random order. So it would try and test the `remove` method before `add`, which obviously always fails. What would be a good approach to performing this kind of tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the test should not rely on execution order. If I would face this issue, I would try to start each of the tests with a prepared database (having then a well-defined state).

Based on the state you can define e.g. the assertions that are part of each test. For example an `add` should increase the size of the database items, if the item was not already contained. For `remove` the size decreases, if the item was contained.

You could make of use the `@Before` and `@After`annotation. Add them to methods that you use to prepare the database (tables).

Answer (score 1):

at start build db in the same way as it's built on production (e.g. flyway). then use `@Before` to reset your db: truncate all the tables, reset sequences, everything.

then in each test, use 'given' phase to prepare data needed for this test: if you test `add`, probably nothing is needed, just add an item and later fetch it. if you are testing unique indexes, add same key twice and assert there is a required error after 2nd insert. if you test `remove`, insert an item (you already tested `add`), remove and assert it's not in database

Comment: I ended up using `@BeforeClass` where I reset and populate the `.db` with all the data needed for the tests.